# JS/bun: how do I access a Google Sheet via the Sheets API, given that I am having the specific problem that I describe below?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, bun

First, my use case: I need to interact with one specific Google Sheet owned by my personal Google account. I want to read a sheet row with foreign words, create an Anki flashcard from that, then update the sheet with the flashcard ID.

I am trying to do this with JS, running on bun instead of node. Once I get it working I intend to compile it into an executable to share with my classmates. ***Using bun allows me to have top-level `await`.***

I am using the [Google Spreadsheet](https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/) package. I'm mostly going by their instructions, while occasionally glancing at Google's official ones.

Therefore, I have already created a specific Project on Google Cloud. Within the Project, I have enabled the Google Drive and Google Sheets APIs. I have also created a Service Account and saved its JSON key file to the project's directory on my machine, at `./api_key.json`. The service account has an email address to which I gave Editor access in my Google Sheet. I've double-checked that my code uses the correct ID from the Google Sheet, taken from its URL.

Now for the code:

```js
import { JWT } from 'google-auth-library';
import { GoogleSpreadsheet } from 'google-spreadsheet';

import credentials from './api_key.json';

const jwt = new JWT({
  email: credentials.client_email,
  key: credentials.private_key,
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'],
});
const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(credentials.file_id, jwt);

await doc.loadInfo();
console.log('Loaded doc info');
console.log(doc.title);
await doc.updateProperties({ title: 'Hello from my script!'})

const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0];
const rows = await sheet.getRows();

console.log(rows);
```

I expected this to do a few things. It should read the spreadsheet info into `doc`, allowing me to manipulate it. It should print its current title and update it to "Hello from my script!", and then print out all the rows.

Instead, what I get is:

```
15 | exports.defaultErrorRedactor = exports.GaxiosError = void 0;
16 | const url_1 = require("url");
17 | /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
18 | class GaxiosError extends Error {
19 |     constructor(message, config, response, error) {
20 |         super(message);
            ^
error: Unable to connect. Is the computer able to access the url?
 code: "ConnectionRefused"

      at new GaxiosError (/home/my_project/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/common.js:20:8)
      at /home/my_project/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:148:18
      at processTicksAndRejections (:55:76)
```

Calling other APIs from the script works. Wrapping everything into an `async` function that I then call makes no difference. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by disconnecting from my VPN.